# Export Hairs in fbx file with Blender 3.6.4

Tags: export, .fbx

I've a mesh in Blender 3.6.4 with some hair.

[image]

I'm trying to export everything to an fbx file.
When I exported everything to the file I obtained the result in the following image

[image]

the related file is 3.6 MB.

So I converted the hair in a mesh, I exported all everything I obtained a file of 5.9 MB but the result is the same, the hair are not visible.

How can I export the hair to an fbx file so that they can be visible?